# Install armhf lib on X86 via apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, apt-get, apt

I am trying to install libluetooth-dev on my laptop, but not the x86 version, the armhf one. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04
Here is how I've tried to do it :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

I then added

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe 
deb [arch=armel,armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial main universe
```

To /etc/apt/sources.list
Then I tried :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a   
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Finally :

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev:armhf
```

Wich outputed :

```
     Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libbluetooth-dev:armhf : Depends: libbluetooth3:armhf (= 5.37-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install all dependencies of libluetooth3, but there is just too much. I also tried to grab a .deb file on the net with the lib and to extract the data, but the file that i need (libluetooth.so) is only a symbolic link in the archive, so I guess that apt is compiling it on install and then updating the dynamic link.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No, apt is not compiling it on install.

Comment: Ok, then why in the files extracted from the .deb, there is a broken symbolic link to the .so file ?

Comment: er, because the libbluetooth.so.3.18.10 which libbluetooth-dev links to is provided by libbluetooth3? That's why it's a _dependency_...

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me figure that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you managed to install armhf packages on xenial?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
sudo apt install aptitude && sudo aptitude install libbluetooth-dev:armhf
```